# How to create a custom Knockout binding that augments the native value binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm creating a custom binding that sets up focus and blur behavior in the init method. Otherwise, I'd like this custom binding to operate exactly like the native Knockout value binding.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.currencyValue = {

init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).focus(function () {
        //focus behavior here...
    });

    $(element).blur(function () {
        //blur behavior here...
    });

   //what do I put here to get the native value binding behavior?
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    //what do I put here to get the native value binding behavior?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `ko.bindingHandlers.value.init` and `ko.bindingHandlers.value.update` functions:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.currencyValue = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
    $(element).focus(function () {
        //focus behavior here...
    });

    $(element).blur(function () {
        //blur behavior here...
    });

   return ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
    return ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had something very similar, but didn't realize I had to return the values from the init and update methods. Thanks for the quick response Artem!

Comment: Odd - Works great for value bindings, but for text bindings it fails with "object has no method of init" when using ko.bindingHandlers.text.init

Answer (score 0):

A slightly **more maintainable and readable solution than [@Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952625/3345644)'s one** - in case someday KO will pass extra parameters to the `init` and `update` functions and that requires less keystrokes:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.currencyValue = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
    $(element).focus(function () {
        //focus behavior here...
    });

    $(element).blur(function () {
        //blur behavior here...
    });

   return ko.bindingHandlers.value.init.apply(this, arguments);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
    return ko.bindingHandlers.value.update.apply(this, arguments);
}
```